# mapDispatchToProps in Widget or just pass props via {...this.props}

Tags: react-native, redux

I have a "widget"-component which needs to execute redux-actions.

Now I see two options:

1) Pass all props from the parent component to the widget via {...this.props}

2) I use mapDispatchToProps() to get the actions in the widget itself

Answer (score 1):

use mapDispatchToProps() if you are using connect() it's probably cleaner but I guess both could be used.